# having a n by n square matrix calculate the sum of prime elements C

Tags: c, matrix

I have this "Having an n by n square matrix calculate the sum of all the prime elements from the main diagonal".

I tried this:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){

  int a[10][10],i,j,sum=0,m,n;

  printf("\nEnter rows and columns: ");
  scanf("%d %d",&m,&n);

  printf("\nEnter elements: ");
  for(i=0;i<m;i++)
      for(j=0;j<n;j++)
           scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
  printf("\nThe matrix is\n");

  for(i=0;i<m;i++){
      printf("\n");
      for(j=0;j<m;j++){
      printf("%d\t",a[i][j]);
      }
 }
 for(i=0;i<m;i++){
     for(j=0;j<n;j++){
          if(i==j)
              sum=sum+a[i][j];
     }
 }
 printf("\n\nSum of the diagonal elements: %d",sum);

 return 0;
}
```

If it's fine how do I calculate the sum of all the **prime** elements from the main diagonal?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should check whether the diagonal element is prime or not.For this you should write a separate function.

```
for(i=0;i<m;i++){
 for(j=0;j<n;j++){
      if(i==j && isprime(a[i][j]))
          sum=sum+a[i][j];
 }
}

int isprime(int a)
{
    for(int i=2;i<=a/2;i++)
       if(a%i==0)
          return 0;
    return 1;
}
//note that you can optimize the above loop by running it till sqrt(a)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I got this 'for' loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 mode". If i declare i i get this " redeclaration of 'i' with no linkage". what is wrong?

Comment: Try declaring `i` outside of the for loop,but inside the `isprime(int a)` function.

Comment: @gauravsehgal It can all be done in one loop, why an inner loop? And, you could have also just run up to the square root of 'i' in the for loop.

Comment: I forgot to remove the int from for loop. Now it's ok. Thank you guys.

Comment: Of all the optimizations possible to `isprime`, you only mention `sqrt(a)`?

Comment: @ZachP The OP had already written this code and asked for help to determine the prime numbers.I tried to keep it as close to his code.Also i have mentioned about the square root part, if he is interested in optimizations.

Comment: @gauravsehgal Yes, sorry, I didn't notice that.